# Can you stream video from GridFS (MongoDB filesystem)?

Tags: mongodb, streaming, gridfs

Can you tell a streaming server such as Ngix to stream videos stored in GridFS? If yes, does it affect perfs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found my anwser on [coffeepowered](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2010/02/17/serving-files-out-of-gridfs/) ([Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20110712174724/http://www.coffeepowered.net/2010/02/17/serving-files-out-of-gridfs/)). To summarize the excellent post of Chris Heald:

- You can do so by using either [gridfs-fuse](http://github.com/mikejs/gridfs-fuse/) or [nginx-gridfs](http://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs)
- You can expect it to be 6 times slower than when you are serving directly from the filesystem.

You should read his benchmark for more details.

Comment: This article is about serving files, not specifically streaming.